# How to check If registry folder is deleted or not

Tags: vb.net, winforms, registry, key

I have created a folder and a sub folder within it and trying to check if the folder exists or not in the registry editor.

This is how I have Created:

```
Dim  kstrRegSubKeyName As String = "CompanyName\\SoftwareName"
Dim oReg As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
oReg = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software", True)
oReg = oReg.CreateSubKey(kstrRegSubKeyName)
oReg = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\" & kstrRegSubKeyName)
```

Now I need to check if that CompanyName Folder is deleted or not and display a message.

How do I do that?

Comment: Try to get a value from that key, if you catch an exception then it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with something like:

```
     Dim rkKey As RegistryKey = Nothing
     Dim Value As New String("CompanyName")
     Dim MainKey as RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software", True)  
    rkKey = MainKey.OpenSubKey(value, True)
    'check to see if the subkey exists
    If rkKey Is Nothing Then 'it doesnt exist
        'Do stuff
    Else
      'Do other stuff
    End If
```